# Order automatically creates an invoice when paying in full with Mageplazza Store Credit

Tags: magento2.4, invoice, store-credit

Paying using Mageplazza extension Store Credit 4.0.0 on Magento 2.4.2. If grand total is zero, an invoice is automatically created. This is not the desired logic.
Mageplazza answered that their module does not do this. What could cause this then ?

Answer (score 0):

Check your **Zero Subtotal Checkout** payment method from Magento admin. There should be one setting called "**Automatically Invoice All Items**" and set that to no.

Comment: I have the exact same settings as the ones dispayed on magento dev docs: https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/payment/zero-subtotal-checkout.html
and there is no such setting; "Automatically Invoice All Items""

Comment: Edit: "Automatically Invoice All Items" setting appears when New Order Status is set to "processing" ! Alas, I need New Order Status to be set to "pending".

Answer (score 0):

Fixed ! "Use system value" had to be checked. That way, no invoice is created.